# permission denied to add current directory to path

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, permission, path

I am trying to install NGC CLI on company's Mac following the instructions given here.

https://ngc.nvidia.com/setup/installers/cli

When I try to run the third command there, which is

```
echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$(pwd)\"" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

I get

```
zsh: permission denied: /Users/rezaafra/.bash_profile
```

The output of `ls -l ~/.bash_profile` is

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  447 Dec  3 08:45 /Users/rezaafra/.bash_profile
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You are trying to add to .bash_profile, not .zshrc

Comment: Also, you are running zsh so adding something to .bash_profile won't help :-)

Comment: Does the problem also occur if you are running bash as your interactive shell? Also, why don't you simply edit the file with a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

The ownership of your .bash_profile seems incorrect. It may be that your company has set it that way on purpose? You could try and fix it with `sudo chown ${USER}:staff ~/.bash_profile`.

The comment about .bash_profile/.zshrc is correct though in that the bash shell has been replaced by zsh in later versions of MacOS. So you likely should be updating a different file. Try and see if
`echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$(pwd)\"" >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc` works.

If all else fails, you can run `export PATH="$PATH:$(pwd)"`. But then, you'll have to do that every time you open a terminal.